# Null constraint on One to many hibernate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jackson

Getting

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "tournament_id" violates not-null constraint`
```

Tournament.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Tournament {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tournament", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Group> groups;}
```

Groups

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(schema = "offan", name = "groups")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_id")
    private Tournament tournament;

    public Group(){}
    public Group(Tournament tournament){
       this.tournament = tournament;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to save both in one go. with `CrudRepository`. Saving just an tournament instance without any groups works fine. I cannot see why groups aren't inserting **tournament_id** key correctly

I'm using lombok for getters and setters.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE tournaments (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) ,
    tournament_id INTEGER REFERENCES tournaments (id) NOT NULL ,
    UNIQUE (name, tournament_id)
);
```

## Possible problem

I use Spring `@RequestBody`which will parse my object into Tournament object, this might not set the mapping correctly?

## ...Was the problem

Parsing the object using the underlying jackson library did not set up the correct mapping. Doing it manually everything was inserted correctly.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tournaments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Tournament createTournament(@RequestBody Tournament tournament){
    //Will not work
    //Tournament savedEntry = tournamentRepository.save(tournament); 
    //

    //Setting properties manually works...
    Tournament t = new Tournament();
    t.setName(tournament.getName());

    Group group = new Group();
    group.setTournament(t);

    t.getGroups().add(group)

    // Both tournament and group are inserted
    t = tournamentRepository.save(t); 

    return t; //Overflow here because of jackson another thing to fix :)
}
```

Comment: Could you add the DDL script?

Comment: @Rocherlee of course!

Comment: your last edit is what I meant by my answer !! :P :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to save `Tournament` entity separately and then set that `Tournament` in the corresponding `Group` entity and then save that `Group`entity separately. (In either case of spring saving group entities or you saving the group entity by mapping corresponding `Tournament` , the number of insert statement remain the same.)

What's happening here is you are expecting Spring to map each `Tournament` to `Group`by calling setters of `Group`, which is not happening.

Comment: Yeah, I've been to this approach before with jooq, having seen multiple blog entries about this it would be nice to save the whole object graph in 'one' go, I don't know how hibernate handle batch inserts but for this small application a once heavy query will not be an issue for now :)